# Return __str__ as result to add to deque?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,entry):
        self.entry = entry

    def __str__(self):
        return "StringName{0}".format(self.entry)
```

that I'm using to return values in a specific format.

(Note: this is an assignment for a class that I'm taking, so this is a requirement to have this class set up like this)

Now I have a need to query from a sqlite3 db. I have a class to add all the records to the database and it works correctly. However, in the class, I'm required to have a method that returns the results of the query as a deque.

I have this function that I'm attempting to do it with:

```
def select_all(self):
    dbconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    dbcursor = dbconnect.cursor()
    double_ended_que = collections.deque()
    for row in dbcursor.execute('SELECT ("(" ||  player_name || ", " || games_played || ", "\
                                || average || ", " || salary || ")") FROM baseball_stats'):
        rowname = print(Test(row))
        double_ended_que.append(rowname)
    dbconnect.close()
    return double_ended_que
```

If I have `rowname = print(Test(row))` then it prints all the row values, then populates the deque with None.

However, if I get rid of print and just have `rowname = Test(row)` then I get the actual class data returned, looking something like `deque([<Test object at 0x00000156FE8F0EB8>, etc etc`

Is there some other way that I can meet both of these requirements? Or should I just create another function in the `Test` class that returns the value in addition to having a `__str__` that does the same thing?

Comment: What exactly needs to be in the `deque`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` outputs to the screen, but it returns `None`, so you're not storing anything useful. If you want to stringify, do:

```
rowname = str(Test(row))  # str delegates to __str__, or __repr__ if __str__ not defined
# Optionally, also print:
print(rowname)
# Then append:
double_ended_que.append(rowname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! That did it for me. :) I'll accept in 10 minutes when it will let me.